# Как узнать боту никнейм человека в сообщении на которое отвечают

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я пишу бота на python. Хочу сделать РП в боте. Как мне сделать так, что бы бот автоматически вставлял в свое сообщение никнейм человека на сообщение которого ответили? Т.е. я ответил на сообщение человека N и боту нужно взять ник этого N человека
Что нужно писать в фигурных скобках ?

```
def text_reply(message):
    if message.reply_to_message == "поцеловать":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"{}")
```

Comment: `message.from_user.first_name` или `message.from_user.last_name` или `message.from_user.username`  (Два последних иногда могут быть `None`)

Comment: пишет только мой никнейм

Comment: Не заметил что нужно на ответ. Вы можете использовать `message.reply_to_message`, чтобы получить сообщение на которое сделан ответ (Оно может быть `None` если сообщение не ответ).

Comment: а как из него получить никнейм другого пользователя ? и свой

Comment: Никнейм другого `message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name` и свой  `message.from_user.first_name`